# MS Surface animating an SVI along a straight line

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, pixelsense

So I'm attempting to move a ScatterViewItem from 1 point to the another.  I've tried using PointAnimation.  However, after the animation completes I can't move the item from the To point.  I can spin the item and scale it, but for some reason can not move it.

It's a simple movement from 1 point to the next in a straight line.  Should I be using PointAnimation or is there a better way?  Thanks I'm doing this in C#

My point animation code:

```
        oPointAnimation = new PointAnimation();
        oPointAnimation.From = new Point(439, 113);
        oPointAnimation.To = new Point(139, 160);

        oPointAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
        oPointAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler(oPointAnimation_Completed);
        theCard.BeginAnimation(ScatterViewItem.CenterProperty, oPointAnimation);
```

Comment: Oh god thank you, I was stuck on this for way too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to use FillBehaviour of the POintAnimation to FillBehavior="Stop"

Answer (score 1):

Although you already have an accepted answer I'd like to add a point here.

Even with FillBehavior set to Stop, there are certain occasions where it just doesn't work. I believe it is in conjunction with [HandoffBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.beginstoryboard.handoffbehavior.aspx) set to SnapshotAndReplace. What I've done in those cases is to programmatically start a new animation (using [BeginAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598906.aspx)) on that dependency property with a `null` as second argument.

```
// Remove all animations for the Opacity property on the myElement element 
myElement.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, null)
```

This effectively clears all animations for that dependency property and you can freely assign new values to it.